# Is it possible to assign an index to ComboBoxItems in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

Is it possible to set a non-default index to a ComboBoxItem that makes up part of the list of items in a ComboBox? (I am thinking of how with an enum I can start the enum value at 1 instead of zero.) I am binding the SelectedIndex to something.

(I know there are a million other ways to bind to a combobox and get index I want, so this is just for the sake of knowing.)

I am looking for something like this.

```
<ComboBox .... >
    <ComboBoxItem Index="1">Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Index="2">Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**
The solution I'm looking for could include a clever hack like inheriting from the ComboBoxItems class and adding an Index property. Anything like that that allows me to use the basic construct above.

Comment: there is [no `Index` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.comboboxitem(v=vs.110).aspx) on `ComboBoxItem`, but there is a `Name` and a `Tag`.

Comment: why are you looking for something like this?

Comment: Product interface requirements call for me to pass the SelectedIndex of a list, but zero index is invalid (in their requirements), and the user doesn't want to see "Invalid" in their combobox. There are plenty of ways to get around this, so I was just curious if I could find the easiest way.

Comment: yep, there are many ways to do it

Comment: If kaqq's answer might be impractical for whatever reason, you might alternatively use the SelectedIndex binding with a custom value converter that converts the 0-based SelectedIndex into some 1-based index and vice versa... (it basically only need to do index = SelectedIndex+1 and SelectedIndex = index-1)

Comment: @elgonzo That is similar to what I have done in the past. I simply incremented `value` in the Property setter that was bound to the index.

Comment: What are you using the index for and how?

Comment: The index is what is stored (bound to a member property and later written to a file) to portray the user's selection in the combobox.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind your ComboBox to `Dictionary<int,string>` and set bindings
as follow:

```
DisplayMemberPath="Value"
SelectedValuePath="Key"
```

Comment: Clever. Although not exactly answering the question I wrote, this definitely falls in the category of stuff I'm looking for.

Comment: definitely not the easiest way ;)

Comment: Despite this, I would rather bind ComboBox ItemSource to my own List<CustomComboItem> then use DisplayMemberPath="Name" and bind SelectedValue to a public property of my DataContextget, by this I can get and set selected item without carrying about control.